# Flex box direction column

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with direction column like in this codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaBNvN?editors=1100

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">

    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
    <div>Item 6</div>
    <div>Item 7</div>
    <div>Item 8</div>
    <div>Item 9</div>
    <div>Item 10</div>
   </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

</div>


    div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

.container .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

I want that the footer is always at bottom.

I tried justify-self: flex-end for the footer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the footer element is a direct child of the flexbox container, the easiest option would be to set the element's `margin-top` to `auto`. This will effectively place the footer element at the bottom of the container.

[**Updated Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/egLqzX)

```
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

If you're curious why this works, here is a quote from the relevant specification regarding `auto` margins on flexbox items:

> [**Flexible Box Layout Module - 8.1. Aligning with auto margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Auto margins on flex items have an effect very similar to auto margins in block flow:
>
> - During calculations of flex bases and flexible lengths, auto margins are treated as 0.
> - Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

As you can see, the remaining free space is distributed in the direction of the `auto` margin.

Answer (score 1):

You're already there, you just need:

```
    div {
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 300px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 200px;
    }

    .header {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container .content {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .footer {
      align-self: flex-end;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Ok it works but I didn't want the space beetwen the divs. Thank you also.

Comment: Ok but the header stretches (I don't want this) however is a good solution